# What rules govern the probability of set difference?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading through a proof of the Inclusion/exclusion principle applied to probability, below are a few lines of the proof, preceding the bit **bolded** where I can't honestly say I understand the jump in a rigorous way:

Given two events $C_1$ and $C_2$ in some sample space, $\mathcal{C}$, we can write them as the union of disjoint sets like such:

$$C_1=(C_1\backslash C_2)\cup(C_1\cap C_2)\\
C_2=(C_2\backslash C_1)\cup(C_1\cap C_2)$$

And therefore their union can be written as

$$(C_1\cup C_2)=(C_1\backslash C_2)\cup(C_1\cap C_2)\cup (C_2 \backslash C_1)$$

Since the above union is also disjoint, we may write the probability of the union as

$$\boldsymbol{P(C_1\cup C_2)=P(C_1\backslash C_2)+P(C_1\cap C_2)+P(C_2 \backslash C_1)\\=P(C_1)+P(C_2)-P(C_1\cap C_2)}$$

Ok, so this makes perfect sense. If you don't subtract the intersection, you will end up double counting any time the union is not disjoint. But in this case, we started with disjoint unions, so I assume there are some rules governing the probability of intersections and\or differences of sets that would help me understand this. If so, I can't find them in my textbook. They skipped straight from the probability of unions being all about that addition action, to this proof.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union  might be careful how you phrase things if this is not what you meant.

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is if 70% of the population has condition A and 40% of the population have condition B what's the lower bound on the amount of people that have both ?  why it's 10%, the amount 40% and 70% have to overlap for the value to not exceed 100% of the population.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes, that makes sense, as I mentioned in the question. However, I don't understand the translation of probability of set difference into minus signs. I can state what's going on in the English language, but it is the jump in logic within the notation that I need to be able to understand, specifically in the bolded line in my question. Can you explain that?

Comment: the minus sign in the $\boldsymbol {=P(C_1)+P(C_2)-P(C_1\cap C_2)}$ part is exactly as you said you'd be counting it twice when the possibilities overlap.  That part is 0 if they don't overlap though.  at least that's my understanding.